# Rails ActiveRecord: default scope on logged-in user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, activerecord, scope

I have a Post model that is associated to users (think of 'post owner').

```
class Post < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :user
  (...)
end
```

In my Post#index action/view, I want to only display posts that belong to the currently logged-in user.

So first approach would have been to somehow set a default scope in the Post model, but as the current_user is known only at runtime, this does not fit in model (in the MVC sense) but rather in the controller.

So, what would be the rails way of implementing a "default scope" in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your User class has an association to their posts like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

Then in your controller you can simply use

```
current_user.posts
```

to get all the posts of the current user

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and cleanest way will be to scope for the current user's posts (right in the controller):

```
current_user.posts
```

You can chain multiple selects on top of it.